# Add tooltips on column headers in a React Bootstrap table

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

```
<BootstrapTable
bordered={false}
hover={true}
wrapperClasses="responsive"
keyField="id"
data={products}
columns={columns} 
{...props.baseProps}
//  ref={(n) => (this.node = n)}
pagination={paginationFactory(optionsPag)} />
```

I want to add the tooltip inside this table. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with provided components Overlay, OverlayTrigger and Tooltip:
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/overlays/

I have created a sandbox with a single table and two tooltips using OverlayTrigger - the first is triggered on hover, the second on click:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-template-forked-29by4e

Comment: I want tooltip text to be the table column text . How can I implement that?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to have a tooltip for each column header?

Comment: yes. I want for each column data.

Comment: are you using a special library for the bootstrap table? it doesn't look like https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/table/. Is it table-next?

Comment: yes I am using react-bootstrap-table-next

Comment: This is essential information, as table-next has completely differenct API than a default react-bootstrap table. 
I would not recommend to use table-next, as it is outdated. The last release is 4 years ago. It has outdated dependencies and it is not compatible with Bootstrap 5.
You can look around for another table library. Personally I migrated from table-next to react-table, because it's headless and easy to use. It looks exactly like a bootstrap table.
I can't provide any help on table-next as the API doesn't offer built-in tooltip on column functionality.